# Bash script runs with two pids

Tags: bash

When I run bash script I am getting two entries in ps list one being child of other .
My script contains just one command

```
test.sh
   sleep 20

pidof test.sh
2494 2493
```

And how can I get the parent PID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run that script, two processes are being created. The first one is the bash interpreter running your script. `sleep` on the other hand is another binary (often in /bin) and thus requires launching of a new process. (although the process naming seems to differ on different systems; when running on my test system neither process was named by test.sh, just bash and sleep).

To get the parent process ID for one or more processes (by ID or name) you might use `ps`:

```
$ ps -p 6194 -o ppid=
 6187

$ ps -p 6194,6748 -o ppid= 
 6187
 6747

$ ps -C bash -o ppid=
 6187
 6747
 6782
```

Answer (score 1):

On a Centos system 'pidof' returned only the parent process.  To obtain the child(ren) you could use 'pstree':

```
$ pidof test.sh
22220
$ pstree -p 22220
mytest(22220)---sleep(22223)
```